# Generate several sql insert from an sql select sentence

Tags: sql, import

How can I generate some insert sql sentences using a specific select query.
Are there any tool from Ms Sql Server 2008? or else?

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do... not sure what you mean under "some insert sql sentences" - paste an example

Comment: @Matthew Vines,@Mark Byers no I don't mean those two answers below;
I told "GENERATE" so I will mail it to my friend and he runs it on his server for the same database..

Comment: @IMHO 
There is a table;
SELECT * FROM X_TABLE WHERE X_CLASS ='A'

It returns 81 rows.
So imagine for those 81 rows, I need a tool to generate 81 lines insert sentences to insert them to a database.

PS: I used to do it with CONCANATE function of EXCEL but, this time there are many rows.. so need a tool ..

Comment: @blgnklc: i think David M's answer is correct

Comment: @Hao Ok I am tying @David M's advice, trying to correct my mistaked, so I think no usefull tools for this job....

Comment: @David M worked fined. Looking for a smart tool ... 
if not ok David M. you rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will generate a list of INSERT statements. You then copy and paste from the output and run the INSERTs. It's far from ideal, but it works.

```
SELECT  'INSERT table (col1, col2)
        VALUES (''' + stringcolumn + ''', ' + CAST(intcolumn AS varchar) + ')'
FROM    sourcetable
```

Comment: this will not handle nulls and the quotes don't look to be escaped properly: `'''`

Comment: The quotes **are** properly escaped, but yes, it won't handle nulls as it is - it's a quick and not comprehensive example.

Comment: Example:
SELECT  'INSERT WFDocTypeField (WFDocTypeID, TableName,FieldName,DMSFieldName)
        VALUES (' + COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(30),WFDocTypeID),'null')   + ', ''' + CAST(TableName AS varchar) + ''', ''' + CAST(FieldName AS varchar) + ''', ''' + CAST(DMSFieldName AS varchar) + ''')'
FROM WFDocTypeField (nolock)
WHERE WFDocTypeID = 852

Thanx @David and @KM

Answer (score 1):

watch out for nulls and data type conversions (SQL Server syntax):

```
SELECT
    'INSERT INTO YourTable (Col_int, Col_datetime, Col_varchar) VALUES ('
        +COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(30),Col_int),'null')
        +','+COALESCE(''''+CONVERT(char(23),Col_datetime,121)+'''','null')
        +','+COALESCE(''''+Col_varchar+'''','null')
        +')'
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT
    'INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (' + Col1 + ', ' + Col2 + ', ' + Col3 + ')'
FROM
    MyTable
```

Of course you will need to encapsulate some fields in quotes, perform some char escaping and convert numbers to varchars, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it row by row? That is a very poor technique when you can insert them all in one query. Databases are designed to perform set operations much faster than row-by-row operations.

```
insert table1 (field1, field2)
Select Field1, Field2 from Table2 where field3 >10
```

Comment: For creating a script that will perform the inserts on a fresh database